# How to implement the schema.prisma @reference(fields:...) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, schema, graphql-js, prisma, prisma-graphql

In the following schema.prisma a relationship between the model Link and Users is created with `postedBy User? @relation(fields: [postedById], reference: [id])`. How can I implement this in MySQL?
The field postedBy, of type User, should link to the User via the User.id field. Since Link.postedBy and User.id are of different data types, the field Link.postedById links to User.id. Now, postedBy needs to be connected to postedById.
I tried to solve this with two FOREIGN KEYs in Link. The first linking postedBy with postedById and the second postedById and User.id. This does not work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
model Link {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  description String
  url         String
  postedBy    User?   @relation(fields: [postedById], references: [id])
  postedById  Int?
}

model User {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String
  email       String  @unique
  password    String  
  links       Link[]
}
```

These are the MySQL queries that I created to get the structure of the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
  id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name      VARCHAR(128),
  email     VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE,
  password  VARCHAR(128),
  links     VARCHAR(256),
  CONSTRAINT Link FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Link(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Link (
  id          INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  createdAt   DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  description VARCHAR(256),
  url         VARCHAR(256),
  postedBy    VARCHAR(128),
  postedById  INT,
  CONSTRAINT author FOREIGN KEY (postedBy) REFERENCES Link(postedById), 
  FOREIGN KEY (postedById) REFERENCES UserId
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
  id        INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name      VARCHAR(128),
  email     VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE,
  password  VARCHAR(128)
);

CREATE TABLE Link (
  id          INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  createdAt   DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  description VARCHAR(256),
  url         VARCHAR(256),
  postedById  INT not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (postedById) REFERENCES User(id)
);
```

this should work

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I would like to know how to create the MySQL queries according to the schema. I amended the queries I created. They throw the error:
ERROR 3780 (HY000): Referencing column 'postedBy' and referenced column 'postedById' in foreign key constraint 'author' are incompatible.